# Can I avoid "redundancy" in this foreign key?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to design a database, and one of my tables is something like this:

Table **player_in_tournament**:

```
ID_tourn | ID_player | and other attributes...
```

and the PK is made up of the two first columns.

In table `tournament_game` (which represents a game/match of the tournament), I want to reference 2 "objects" from the player_in_tournament, so I should have two foreign keys, and each of the are composed by a ID_player and a ID_tour.

But the `ID_tour` is the same in both "objects".

The question is if it's a good idea to change the PK of the first table and add a `ID_player_in_tournament`, and use it like foreign key in the `tournament_game` table.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data so we can see what you want to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a surrogate key to `player_in_tournament` table makes it possible to construct a `tournament_game` that represents players with two different `ID_tourn`. This avoids redundancy at the expense of allowing inconsistency.

You should have three fields participating in two foreign keys -

- `(ID_tourn, ID_player1)` for the first `player_in_tournament` row
- `(ID_tourn, ID_player2)` for the second `player_in_tournament` row

Note that the same column `ID_tourn` participates in two foreign key relationships:

```
create table player_in_tournament(
    ID_tourn int
,   ID_player int
,   ...
,   primary key(ID_tourn, ID_player)
);
create table tournament_game(
    ID_tourn int
,   ID_player1 int
,   ID_player2 int
,   ...
,   foreign key (ID_tourn, ID_player1)
        references player_in_tournament(ID_tourn, ID_player)
,   foreign key (ID_tourn, ID_player2)
        references player_in_tournament(ID_tourn, ID_player)
);
```

Comment: that's true! I had not thought in the inconsistency problem... And also I didn't  know that the ID_tourn column of tournament_game can be used in this way (participating in two foreign keys). Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly surmise, this will make the foreign key in table `tournament_game` only two columns wide instead of four, which will improve the convenience and readability of joins that you need to write in SQL statements. The only downside is the increase in table width, but that is only a few bytes per row. This, as you may know, is called a "surrogate key" (as opposed to a "natural key").
If you do this, make sure you leave  a unique key or constraint on the "Natural key" (`ID_tourn, ID_player`) to ensure that these two fields retain uniqueness and the table retains data consistency.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 tables here Table player_in_tournament and tournament_game .As the name suggests tournament_game is the table about tournament in games so it  should have tournament id and tournament name and all the other attributes related to tournament . And the other table player_in_tournament should have player id , player name and tournament id (reference from tournament_game table) and the other attributes related to player . This should be design as per your query .

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a tournament. You have given it an artificial identifier you call ID_tourn. That's probably because there is no real name or number like tournament 2016Q3 for it. (If it were, you could just use this tournament number and didn't have to artificially add an ID.)

Then you have players. Here again you create an ID. Probably because they are real life players without any natural identification number. (If they were just players in your game, they'd have a login or user name you could use instead.)

Now you have players in a tournament. A record is naturally identified by the tournament identifier and the player identifier.

At last you have a tournament game, obviously a match of two tournament players. So a record would contain the tournament identifier and two player identifiers. It would contain two foreign keys: ID_tourn + ID_player1 and ID_tourn + ID_player2.

All this, working with composite keys and natural keys like a login name where possible, is one concept of creating a database. Another is giving *every* table an artificial ID and link tables by these. I have worked with both on large databases and prefer the first concept, but there are others who prefer the all-IDs concept.

Here is an example how the two compare. PK = primary key, FKn = foreign key, PK2 = unique constraint (like a second PK)

**Natural keys / composite keys**

- table client (client_number) *=> PK(client_number)*
- table item (item_number, description, price) *=> PK(item_number)*
- table order (order_number, order_date, client_number) *=> PK(order_number); FK1(client.client_number)*
- table order_item (order_number, item_number, amount) *=> PK(order_number,item_number); FK1(order.order_number); FK2(item.item_number)*

**Artikficial IDs**

- table client (id_client, client_number) *=> PK(id_client); PK2(client_number)*
- table item (id_item, item_number, description, price) *=> PK(id_item); PK2(item_number)*
- table order (id_order, order_number, order_date, client_number) *=> PK(id_order); PK2(order_number), FK1(client.client_number)*
- table order_item (id_order_item, order_number, item_number, amount) *=> PK(id_order_item); PK2(order_number,item_number); FK1(order.order_number); FK2(item.item_number)*